# Create a Function for the .append in FormData depending on the length of the array.

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
    onSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    var stringers = this.state.tags
    var tagarray = stringers.split(",");
    const formData = new FormData()
    formData.append('material[tags]', tagarray)
```

*(`this.state.tags` is from an `<Input>`)*

I have this on my `onSubmit` function. It won't run because it is a wrong code.

**My question is:** For Example, my `this.state.tags` contains `"Apples,Oranges,Strawberries"`, It will be converted to an array `tagarray` with the value of

```
["Apple", "Oranges", "Strawberries"]
0: "Apples"
1: "Orange"
2: "Strawberries"
length: 3
```

Now, I have said earlier that the above code is wrong. Why? 
Because, If I am passing 3 values from the array, my `formData.append` should be like

```
formData.append('material[tags][0]', //one array value(Apples) here)
formData.append('material[tags][1]', //one array value(Oranges) here)
formData.append('material[tags][2]', //one array value(Strawberries) here)
```

But I can't make it fixed like that. I have to create a function that evaluates how many values are in the array and then that function must create the needed `formData.append` so I can pass it down to my axios later on. How do I create that? I am new in Javascript and ReactJS so Please help me. thanks!

Comment: have you tried `tagarray.forEach(tag => formData.append('material[tags]', tag));` ? you can append multiple times the same key to send an array. If your backend is not standard (i.e. php) try using `material[tags][]` as key instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use forEach() and template literals like so:

```
const formData = new FormData();
tagarray.forEach((value, index) => formData.append(`material[tags][${index}]`, value));
```